# Pass a QWidget to a QPushButton after QWidget has been passed to another class (Button does not show)

Tags: c++, qt

In my QMainWindow instance this works fine:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    QStringList labels;
    labels << tr("Title") << tr("Location");

    widget = new QWidget;

    setCentralWidget(widget);
    QPushButton *b = new QPushButton(widget);

}
```

but when the widget is passed like this `XmlReader reader(widget);` and i want to do the same in the constructor of `XmlReader` instead of `MainWindow` like:

```
XmlReader::XmlReader(QWidget *widget)
    : widget(widget)
{
    QPushButton *b = new QPushButton(widget);
}
```

it doesn't show. Why?

**EDIT: It works like described below, but still it does not work inside of XmlReader**

OK This is an extract from the src of the sublassed widget. I now call `show()` in `createButton()`

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
}

void Widget::createButton()
{
    QPushButton *b = new QPushButton(this);
    b.show()
}
```

Then in XmlReader i call widget->createButton() and the button is shown. Works for me.

But still, calling QPushButton b = new QPushButton(widget) and b.show() inside XmlReader won't show a button. Shouldn't it be the same?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is too short. What kind of widget is 'widget'? Do you call show() anywhere for 'widget' or the button? Are you using a layout for widget? Do you add the button to the layout anyhwere?

Comment: actually `show()` did the job. `setCentralWidget()` or using a layout seen to take care of this. `widget` is just a QWidget subclass with additional methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong: parentness have closely nothing to displaying objects.

You must use lauot mechanish to put buttons where you need, or use setGeometry method

Comment: please clarify your answer since it does work without `setGeometry` or using a layout.

Comment: @tobilocker explain what you are trying to do. Why you are trying to create buttons inside XmlReader? What is XmlReader? How you are using it?